# Gensim: Manual generation of training tuples of (target, context, label)

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I am asking this question as a lazy researcher who just wants to try out random crazy ideas quickly, without spending a ton of time reinventing wheels. I completely understand these aren't the intended use cases.

To test a number of hypothesis, I would love to

- generate the (target, context, +1) tuples differently, instead of the default sliding window.
- generate the negative samples (target, random_context, -1) tuples based on some rules, instead of from random NCE draws.

For example, I can get the parse tree of a sentence and use parent-child relationship to generate tuples, which is a non-linear window(somebody already tried it in NLP research community, hand-coded ofc...). I can also get an antonyms dictionary to lookup and to generate more negative samples in addition to the random ones (not sure, may help with faster convergence).

Are there some private member functions (something that starts with `_XX`)I can override to achieve these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are not easy extension-points for changing the (context->word) training-examples, or negative-example sampling.

Of course the full source code is available, and thus anything's possible as patches, or by using the existing code as a starting-point. Practically, however, the key loops/decisions about these steps are only efficiently run from inside the optimized Cython training routines – which are a bit harder to read/adapt/test/deploy.

(There's [an open issue #1623](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/1623) to re-factor the code to make such related variants of Word2Vec easier to implement. But the project's prior effort to ostensibly meet this need, [PR #1777](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/pull/1777), was somewhat of a disaster, adding more layers of indirection and scattering key operations across new classes, without offering the sorts of extension-points that were really needed.)